# Pointer variable of a linked list: difference between the variable, reference to the variable, and pointer to the variable

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

in C I was playing around with a linked list and seeing what `printf` will display when passing various versions of the variable names.

```
typedef struct node{
    int node_value
    struct node *next;
} list_node;

int main(){
list_node *list;    

list = getnode();
printf("address of *list %d\n", &list);
printf("list->next of *list %d\n", list);
printf("list->next of *list %d\n", list->next);
printf("double pointer **list %d\n", *list);

return 0;
}
```

`*list` will print the `node_value`

But what is the difference between `&list and list`?  I know and & is a reference to the variable, and the variable name without the * is the address of the first entry.  However, when I get different values when outputting the two.

Thanks.

Comment: `However, when I get different values when outputting the two.` Of course you get different values. `list` is the address to the list, `&list` is __the address to the pointer to list__.

Comment: BTW for printing pointer values you should use `%p` instead of `%d`.

Comment: I had a question...no one has to bash it.  So what if I'm still learning, I thought the developer community was a bit more open minded.

Comment: Surprisingly an apple has different properties than a banana. And `main` has a wrong signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No!** You're talking some mix-up of C and C++. This is C code. **C does not have references.**

The `&` operator can be applied to objects in order to retrieve their address in memory, yielding a pointer, in both C and C++. It ain't got nothing to do with references. Even in C++.

In C++, you can use the ampersand character (`&`) to **define a reference**:

```
int i;
int& b = i;    // reference referencing i
```

This is not possible in C, though.

---

BTW, `printf` uses specific format specifiers for specific types. `%d` is for `int`s. For pointers (like `&i`), use `%p`. Wrong usage of the wrong format specifier is undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Hi as stated above by you that &list represents reference type but according to me difference is that in &list which is your reference type i.e the value is stored in the heap and the reference to the value is stored in a stack  whereas simply typing list is like declaring a value type to store a value and which can also be made generic.